# Is there a way to mimic tabview using the details tag?

Tags: css

CMS issues preclude me from using tabview, so I've been looking at alternatives to get similar content organization.

I'm not really concerning myself with browser compatibility since this is more of a personal, abstract effort, ergo I've been looking at the `<details>` tag.  Ideally, I'd like to do it without pseudo-classes (I'd like to be able to transfer it to inline CSS for other *really stupidly backward* CMS reasons).  An extension effort of this that I've been puzzling over is the use of `<details>` as a checkbox alternative for similar reasons (CMS limitations preclude me from using checkbox hacks; *believe me, I know how insane this sounds*).

But before I dedicate a lot of time to trying to figure this out, is it even possible to 'recreate' the tabview effect with `<details>` and `<summary>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple `TL;DR` answer (if I read your question right) is 'NO'. But...

The longer answer is a resounding 'YES'. `<details>` and `<summary>` are semantic elements, so they are basically just divs with a different name - you get no extra functionality with them. However, if you give the details tag a `tabindex` it would become selectable, and you could then style the show / hide functionality through CSS.

Not being sure how you would want to implement this on your page it's tricky to give a complete answer, but as an example:

In HTML

```
<details tabindex="0">
    Heading
    <summary>Interesting factoids...</summary>
</details>
```

And in the CSS...

```
summary {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0px;
    height: auto;
}

details:focus summary {
    max-height: unset;
}
```

This would make the summary 0px in height by default, but would expand it when its parent container is clicked (focused).

You might need to play about with the details a bit for your particular use case, but CSS is the way to go.